# Расположение элементов из базы данных на странице

Tags: php, база-данных, sqlite, websqldatabase

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы элементы из базы данных располагались в строку по 3, а не в столбец с новой строки.

```html
<?php foreach ($ds as $ds) : ?>
 
<div class="container">
    <div class="dc clearfix">
     <div class="dc__item">
      <img src="<? echo $ds['img']; ?>" alt="Ds" width="150" height="150">
      <a href="dc_page.html"><h3><? echo $ds['Title_name']; ?></h3></a>
      <p1>
       <? echo $ds['experience']; ?>
      </p1>
      <p><? echo $ds['aess']; ?></p>
      <h5><? echo $ds['ne']; ?></h5>
      <? echo $ds['rng']; ?>
     </div>
                     </div>

<hr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверное flex'ить в css ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решено!**

Открыл контейнер в другом php файле и после, в следующем php файле подключился к бд и вывел элементы . Теперь каждый раз контейнер не создает.

Answer (score 0):

указать элементам `display:inline-block` и размер в процентах, чтобы влазило только 3 элементами.
или как сказал FlowGraph, сделать элементы flex и расставить их как надо.
тоже само можно сделать и с grid, что даже,наверное, быстрее будет, чем с флексами.

Comment: У меня новая запись в базе данных отображается на сайте с новой строки в столбик. Хоть как не описывай в css - все равно. ЧТо я не так делаю?

Comment: Я так понял, ошибка в том, что всегда создается container и в нем один dc__item, а нужен один container и несколько dc__item в нем